# Localized Form Submission using Ajax

Tags: ajax

I am using springs framework with Tomcat 7 & MySQL. I am using UTF-8 encoding to submit form data for Local Language. This works fine using post through a JSP. However, when using Ajax Based Form submission it shows junk characters as request parameters in server.

Please let me know if I am missing anything..

```
** My Ajax Code**

    xmlHttp.open("POST", "viewTeluguScript.htm", true);
    //xmlHttp.setRequestHeader("Content-type", "multipart/form-data;charset=UTF-8");
    xmlHttp.setRequestHeader("Content-length", parameters.length);
    // xmlHttp.setRequestHeader("Content-Type", "text/html;charset=UTF-8");
    xmlHttp.setRequestHeader("Content-type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded;charset=UTF-8");
    //xmlHttp.setRequestHeader("pageEncoding","UTF-8");
    //xmlHttp.setRequestHeader("accept-charset","UTF-8");
    xmlHttp.setRequestHeader("content-language","tel");
    xmlHttp.setRequestHeader("Connection", "close");
    xmlHttp.send(parameters);


    **My Controller code**

    public ModelAndView viewTeluguScript(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws SQLException, CannotGetJdbcConnectionException, Exception {

    //textInfo = java.net.URLDecoder.decode(request.getParameter("teluguText"), "UTF-8");
    textInfo = request.getParameter("teluguText");
    /* StringBuffer jb = new StringBuffer();
    String line = null;
    try {
    BufferedReader reader = request.getReader();
    while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null)
    jb.append(line);
    } catch (Exception e) { 


    }

    System.out.println("request is :::: "+jb.toString());*/


    ModelAndView mv = new ModelAndView("viewQuestions");
    //request.getSession().setAttribute("workingModule", "questions");
    return mv;
    }


        enter code here

    **My web.xml**
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <web-app version="2.5" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd">


        <context-param>
            <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
            <param-value>

                /WEB-INF/applicationContext-security.xml
                classpath:applicationContext-common-business.xml
                classpath:applicationContext-common-authorization.xml
            </param-value>
        </context-param>

        <filter>
            <filter-name>encodingFilter</filter-name>
            <filter-class>org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter</filter-class>
            <init-param>
                <param-name>encoding</param-name>
                <param-value>UTF-8</param-value>
            </init-param>
            <init-param>
                <param-name>forceEncoding</param-name>
                <param-value>true</param-value>
            </init-param>
        </filter>

        <locale-encoding-mapping-list>
            <locale-encoding-mapping>
                <locale>en</locale>
                <encoding>UTF-8</encoding>
            </locale-encoding-mapping>
            <locale-encoding-mapping>
                <locale>tel</locale>
                <encoding>UTF-8</encoding>
            </locale-encoding-mapping>

        </locale-encoding-mapping-list>


        <filter-mapping>
            <filter-name>encodingFilter</filter-name>
            <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
        </filter-mapping>

        <filter>
            <filter-name>springSecurityFilterChain</filter-name>
            <filter-class>org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy</filter-class>
        </filter>
        <filter-mapping>
            <filter-name>springSecurityFilterChain</filter-name>
            <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
        </filter-mapping>
        <listener>
            <listener-class>org.springframework.security.web.session.HttpSessionEventPublisher</listener-class>
        </listener>
        <listener>
            <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener</listener-class>
        </listener>
        <servlet>
            <servlet-name>g2l</servlet-name>
            <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
            <!--<load-on-startup>2</load-on-startup>-->
        </servlet>
        <servlet-mapping>
            <servlet-name>g2l</servlet-name>
            <url-pattern>*.htm</url-pattern>
        </servlet-mapping>
       <!-- <session-config>
            <session-timeout>
                30
            </session-timeout>
        </session-config>
        <welcome-file-list>
            <welcome-file>redirect.jsp</welcome-file>
        </welcome-file-list>-->
    </web-app>
```

Answer (score 0):

try adding a content-encoding http header 
your browser uses Unicode to represent data to display. Resources coming from a web server can optionally have encoding information attached in http header. 
If there is a content-encoding header, the browser converts the resource to the internal unicode representation using encoding from the response header. If there is no content-encoding header, the browser assumes, that the file encoding is the same as the page which requested the resource.

Comment: Tried  xmlHttp.setRequestHeader("Content-encoding","UTF-8"); However its not working. Thanks for your suggesstion